# redis.js get is returning true instead of the value

Tags: javascript, node-redis

I am trying to return the value of the salt to my function but all I am getting is true.

```
function getUserSalt(client, username) {

    let salt = client.HGET(username, "salt", function (error, result){
        if(error) throw error;

        return result;
    })

    return salt;
}
```

Comment: Is HGET an async function? in that case, you should use promises to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the callbacks incorrectly.

```js
function getUserSalt(client, username, callback) {

return client.HGET(username, "salt", callback);

}
```

Now, this can be used with a callback, which will receive error as its first argument, and salt as it's second.

Alternatively, you can use promises as described here: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#promises

A sample would be:

```js
const {promisify} = require('util');
const getUserSaltAsync = promisify(getUserSalt);

getUserSaltAsync(client, "some_username").then(salt => {console.log(salt);});
```

Of course, you'd also need to handle errors from the promises somehow.

Comment: Thanks! I have never learned how to use async js or even what a callback was. So now I know what to learn moving forward. Is there any sites or places that helped you learn this topic that you could recommend?

Comment: I'd recommend to learn about callbacks first, then continue to promises, then to async/await. In production, I'd recommend to move away from callbacks or sync code entirely, because there are problems like callback hell, for example.

As per where to learn that - I am not sure as I never learned it all in one place. 

This seems to be close to the topic: https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies.

Per learning what a callback is - I'd recommend googling up what synchronous or asynchronous in node means.

P.S. It posts comments on enter, hence the edit.

Comment: Will definitely do that. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import redisClient from "../config/redisConfig";
import util from "util";
let hgetall = util.promisify(redisClient.hgetall).bind(redisClient);

await hgetall("key") // This way you will be getting the value instead of true
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.